# How to share values between classes without using globals?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I built 5 UITableViews: *Continent, Country, Subcountry, Region* and *Subregion* respectively.

The data for every `UITableView` is being stored in a database.

On every navigation I retrieve essential data and pass (`prepareToSegue`) it to next `UITableView` with the set of token variables I defined in every class. All are similar.

```
Continent(country.ContinentID=self.continentID) 
       --> Country (region.CountryID=self.countryID)
```

I have a feeling that I am doing it wrong, in some kind of ugly way. Can you advice me how to implement this task more smart and, lets assume, in professional way? I'd like to get rid of this bundle of int vars in every class.

P.S Please don't advise using global variables. I read about them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357187/when-are-global-variables-acceptable), and the globals are defined as more-evil-than a `goto` statement.

Comment: +1 for no globals or pseudo-globals for this kind of thing (seems everyone wants to throw every piece of data in their app into the app delegate...). I guess the only thing I'd do differently is create objects encapsulating the data you're passing around and pass those to the appropriate controllers. Definitely would like to see others answers though.

Comment: Globals/singletons have their use, but it is wise to look elsewhere first.  What you probably want is roughly what Carl describes -- some sort of state object that reflects the overall state of your set of classes.  None of the "mainstream" imperative languages has a good facility for this, though, so you have to pass the object around somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to create all controllers by a separate class that would keep track of the essential data and pass them to the controllers as needed during creation. This is illustrated in my [sample Xcode project on GitHub](http://github.com/zoul/Singletons-Suck). Stay away from singletons, they are little more than glorified globals and there are many good arguments against them (some of which are explained in [this blog post](http://zmotula.tumblr.com/post/1390385240/why-singletons-suck)).

Comment: Wouldn't there be some kind of application footprint increase and memory pollution?

Comment: Not really. There's just one extra class that takes care of creating the “dependency-heavy” objects, and taking out the singleton boilerplate code and refactoring the dependency management into a separate class actually makes the resulting design simpler.

Comment: Actually, this is a not-unreasonable solution to the problem of the missing feature I noted above.  Basically the related classes are created out of a "factory" that initializes them (somehow) with addressability to the needed common data.

Comment: In principle it's the idea of object-oriented design: having isolated building blocks that are assembled together as needed. Singletons just glue your classes together in a way that requires class code changes to reassemble into a different shape.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the Singleton design pattern to answer your needs - Creating a "DataManager" to hold and maintain all your data objects so that you can access them from anywhere across your controllers is convenient and if you implement it [correctly](http://lukeredpath.co.uk/blog/a-note-on-objective-c-singletons.html), it ensures persistence and good performance.

Comment: A singleton is really just a global in wolf's clothing.

Comment: I like the analogy, but I strongly disagree. For one we're talking about a class vs. a variable - a class has much more ability to make sure things are done right (especially in terms of working in a multithreaded environment)

Comment: I think that's an OK solution for providing an object that each view controller fetches data from. But for passing the information from one controller to another as part of drilling down a navigation stack, this doesn't make as much sense - the controller that instantiates a "detail" controller knows which item the detail controller should show - and should tell it at the time of presentation, rather than sending that info off to a singleton.

Comment: @Hot Licks Some guys disagree. Yesterday I had fun reading the tantrums the guys were throwing. There's much cons and pros about the subject.

Comment: I totally agree with @Carl Veazey, this design pattern makes much more sense as a general data model and not for the specific case of "drilling down". If this is the only case then I say lose the singleton, but if some non-trivial data transfer needs to take place - that's about the time to start considering it.

Comment: @Stavash Is "DataManager" some kind of my special NSObject subclass that will hold all the immense of my ints?

Comment: It's an example of a naming convention for a singleton object that will of course be used to maintain your data.

Comment: There are about a hundred reasons for not using globals.  To my knowledge, singletons only (partially) address two of those reasons.  Not a big improvement.

Comment: Not a matter of numbers. It really depends on the case, doesn't it?

Comment: It does. In 99 cases out of 100 singletons are a bad idea.

Comment: @zoul for something like the application's database, where there is a single db connection app-wide with methods that provide a Model-centric API, do you think a singleton is appropriate?

Comment: Even in that case I think it’s more appropriate to keep the DB a regular object and arrange the objects to share the pointer without singletons. (It’s what works for me. As an example, it makes it easier to use a testing or mock DB instead of the production one.)